# Cannot access data in the callback of a XMLHttpRequest in jQuery

Tags: jquery, get, xmlhttprequest

When I run the following XmlHttpRequest

```
$.get('../entries/find_most_recent',
    {name:$("#name").val()}, 
    function(data) {
        console.log("data");
    });
```

The result can be seen in this Firebug screenshot:

[image]

But when I remove the quotes from console.log("data"), like so:

```
$.get('../entries/find_most_recent',
    {name:$("#name").val()}, 
    function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Nothing comes up in Firebug. The response is just a string, as can be seen in the screenshot above. How do I access it? Thanks for reading.

Comment: If I get you right, the `Response` tab is empty if you remove the quotes? Sounds pretty much impossible, since the point where you receive the `response` is way before any `javascript` comes into play.

Comment: Agreed. What you're doing with `console.log("data");` is logging the string `data` (which correctly appears in the bottom of the screen shot). The actual `data` or the request is unrelated. Could this be a Firebug bug?

Comment: @jAndy & MvanGeest - I put data in quotes in the first code block just to check that I was getting into the callback, and included the screenshot to show that the request is getting the data okay. But when I try to run console.log(data), nothing is outputted to the Firebug console.

Comment: But even if you call `console.log(data)` the `Response Tab` from Firebug should display `hey`. I can't tell why `Firebug` does not display the string. You should try to set the `dataType` to **text** within your `$.get()` request.

Answer (score 1):

The object returned needs to be determined and dealt with appropriately.

From jquery.com
"The success callback function is passed the returned data, which will be an XML root element, text string, JavaScript file, or JSON object, depending on the MIME type of the response. It is also passed the text status of the response."

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Answer (score 0):

I would have to say try setting your dataType to text in your $.get request and also double check "../entries/find_most_recent" for any errors (should their be an extension, like: ../entries/find_most_recent.cgi or .html or .php or etc.)